# sage plot3d fails - browser opens, but then hangs. Sometimes, I get an error that a file cannot be read

Tags: three.js, sage

When I run the example of how to do a 3D plot, the browser opens, but sometimes it hangs and sometimes it gives an error message that a file in file////home/jeffs/.sage/temp/jeffs-desktop/780876 cannot be read, either because of a protection error or the file is missing.

The file is there alright.  I also tried protecting the entire file tree 777.  That would cause the browser to hang, even if looking at file:////home/jeffs/.sage (if I look at file:////home/jeffs, the browser works wonderfully so I think it is not a browser problem.)

Here is the sequence of commands I am using.

```
sage: x, y = var('x,y')
sage: plot3d(x^2 + y^2, (x,-2,2), (y,-2,2))
Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
sage:
```

Normally, I use chromium Version 113.0.5672.63 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).  If I use Goggle chrome, then I use 113.0.5672.92 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Google chrome works better on the directories in the path to the HTML file, but still won't work on the HTML file, it just hangs.  If I look in the developer tools, then I can see the HTML code, which is a menu with 4 options.

Plotting in 2D works quite nicely.  Not sure that's relevant.

I am a sage newbie.  I have just installed sage 9.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Thank you

Jeff

I verified that the file the browser was looking for was present and protected such that it was readable.
I made every file in the path to the temporary file protected 777.
I tested with Lynx, and that works until it renders the menu.  The menu invokes javascript functions, so I would not expect lynx to work.
I tested with google chrome and chromium.  Neither browser works well, but chrome works better at rendering files in the path.
I did an apt-update and apt-upgrade and got a new version of Google Chrome (113.0.5672.126-1).  I can see the HTML and javascript if I pressd control-U.
I checked that the files in `/usr/share/javascript/three` are present and world readable.